# 2D Collision Detection

Tags: c#, game, winforms, windows, collision

I wrote this a while ago but wanted to see if I went about it the right way and if my brain is working correctly. I was thinking about these two projects the other day and I recently released the source. This game was originally for a Windows Form Game Jam so you have full context.

This code worked but I always felt there were inaccuracies in how it handled it. For example, there had been times a rock would clip through a ship.

```
private void CollisionDetection()
{
    foreach(PictureBox s in rocks)
    {
        //These tell the difference between, I'm not sure if this is all correct, its just what I came up with.
        int Xdifference = (s.Location.X + (s.Width / 2)) - (player.Location.X + (player.Width / 2));
        int Ydifference = (s.Location.Y + (s.Height/ 2)) - (player.Location.Y + (player.Height/ 2));

        //get the actual distance apart
        double dist = Math.Sqrt((Xdifference * Xdifference) + (Ydifference * Ydifference));

        //And finally, does the real comparison
        if(dist < ((s.Width / 2) + (player.Width / 2)) && damagable)
        {
            health -= 10;
            damagable = false;
            impactHit.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Full file is found [here](https://github.com/TylerCode/FlyAway/blob/1ff462ef22f5d43e8dd9a619f65766954036fad4/FormGameJam/Form1.cs) and full source, [here](https://github.com/TylerCode/FlyAway/tree/1ff462ef22f5d43e8dd9a619f65766954036fad4).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Collision detection

You can calculate the collision much easier with the [`Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) structure.

Use the [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you are interested in single points that

> Determines if the specified point is contained within this Rectangle structure.

```
var pictureRect = new Rectangle(
    pictureBox.Location.X, 
    pictureBox.Location.Y, 
    pictureBox.Width, 
    pictureBox.Height
);
var isCollision = pictureRect.Contains(player.Location.X, player.Location.Y);
```

---

If you want to know whether the rectangles have a collision then use the  [`IntersectsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method that

> Determines if this rectangle intersects with rect.

```
var isCollision = pictureRect.IntersectsWith(player.Rectangle());
```

---

Create and an extension to easier get the rectangle from a `PictureBox`.

```
public static Rectangle Rectangle(this PictureBox pictureBox)
{
    return new Rectangle(
        pictureBox.Location.X, 
        pictureBox.Location.Y, 
        pictureBox.Width, 
        pictureBox.Height
    );
}
```

---

## Naming

> ```
> foreach(PictureBox s in rocks)
> ```

You should use more meaningful names than just `s`. A variable like `pictureBox` or `pb` would be much better because it's derived from the collection. The `s` does not have any meaning. Although in this case a `rock` would be perfect.

---

## Health & Damage

> ```
> health -= 10;
> ```

This operation is not clear at first and maybe you have other places where you need to decrease health. Consider using constants and a *helper* method for this.

```
private static class Damage
{
    public const int WhenHitRock = 10;
}

void DecreaseHealth(int value)
{
     health -= value;
}
```

---

## Everything together

The result of applying all suggestions and proper names would be a self-documenting code that no longer has to be commented.

When you write comments you only should explain *why* you are doing something because the code already shows *what*.

```
foreach (var rock in rocks)
{       
    var isPlayerRockCollision = rock.Rectangle().IntesectsWith(player.Rectangle());
    if (isPlayerRockCollision)
    {
        DecreaseHealthBy(Damage.WhenHitRock);
        damagable = false;
        impactHit.Play();
        return;
    }
}
```

Notice that there is a `return` inside the `if`. You set the `demagable` to `false` so I think it's not necessary to test other rocks for a hit. You can stop at the first one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. `IntersectsWith()` is the method if you need to detect collisions 95% of the time.

Comment: Added as accepted answer. It kept getting edited and got better and better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TylerC yeah, the ideas kept comming so I needed to edit it multiple times - hope it helps ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t this is perfect, I wasn't sure I was going about it the right way. I appreciate the time and effort you put into this.

Comment: I would recommend at least mentioning _quad trees_ at some point, as this solutuion does not scale well.

Comment: @NumLock I've googled for it and this sounds like a good idea - at least for _more_ complex projects but I've never used it myself before. You're welcome to add a review about it.

Answer (score 7):

Just a quick answer.

- You are calculating `s.Width / 2` for each `Picturebox` two times. Just calculate it once, store the result in a variable and use the variable.
- You are calculating `player.Width / 2` twice for each `Picturebox` which should be done outside of the loop and stored in a variable. The same applies to the calculation of `player.Height/ 2`. This values won't change unless they are changed inside `impactHit.Play()`.
- You should check in the `if` condition first if `damageble` is true because its faster .

Comment: Thanks for the help, on the third though: If the first condition is false it skips the second calculation?

Comment: Yes thats right when using the `&&` operator.

Comment: @Heslacher `(player.Location.X + (player.Width / 2))` can all be calculated before the loop, same with `Y` / `Height`.

Comment: Likewise, you should test performance between the current code and `(int)(s.Location.X * 1.5)` (same with `Y`).